# std::vector definition in struct

Tags: c++, vector, std

I defined a structure as follows.

```
extern int x;
a = 1;
b = 2;
x = a*b;
struct  bStruct
{
    unsigned long   Cycles;                     
    unsigned long   Time;                                           
    std::vector<unsigned long> Chunks(x);
};
```

but `x` in the Chunks definition is noted as an error with a red line underneath it.

The error message is:

> variable "x" is not a type name.

Why did this error happen, and how do I fix it?

Comment: With this string `std::vector<unsigned long> Chunks(x);` what do you want to do? set the size of vector to x? if you use C++98 there is no constructor with one `int` argument try this `std::vector<unsigned long> Chunks(x, 0);` or you can init this vector in constructor of bStruct.

Comment: Get a [book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). You can't learn C++ via StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful input! I will check out the books.

Answer (score 4):

Your compiler thinks that `Chunks` is a function, parsing it like so:

```
std::vector<unsigned long> Chunks( x );
            |               |      |
            |               |      +---Wait a sec huh ? what type is 'x' ?? 
            |               |
            |               +---------Function name Chunks
            +----------Return Type std::vector<unsigned long>
```

You want `Chunks` to be a *data* member, which you need to initialize using:

```
struct bStruct
{
    unsigned long Cycles;                     
    unsigned long Time;                                           
    std::vector<unsigned long> Chunks;

    bStruct() : Chunks(x)
    {
      // Constructor
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works! I am very new to C++, so please bear with me. I have some more questions: 1 Why is there brackets in bStruct(): Chunks? Why it is not bStruct(). Chunks? 2 Why std::vector<unsigned long>(x) instead of just x? 3 What is the usage of the curly brackets in the end? Thanks!

Comment: The last line here defines the `bStruct`'s constructor, and this constructor initializes `Chunks` with `std::vector<unsigned long>(x)` using an initialization list (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list), though there might be some clearer explanation for a beginner out there)

Comment: it is a default constructor(without arguments). after `:` it is an initializing list, this means that variable `Chunks` of `bStruct` inits with std::vector<unsigned long>(x), and `{}` it is empty body of constructor. it same to `bStruct(){Chunks =  std::vector<unsigned long>(x); }`

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining in such details. I am really glad I found Stackoverflow today!

Comment: @goosli: _"Why std::vector<unsigned long>(x) instead of just x"_ Good question. In fact, just `x` is fine. I've edited this answer a bit.

Comment: @MikeMinaev: It's not the "same". One is an initialisation; the other is a default initialisation followed by an assignment. Try it with a `const` member and you'll soon see the difference.

Comment: There are so many smart people here! I have one more dumb question please. (I will go to read books to learn C++ afterwards) I tried to use this method to define a few arrays with with variable array sizes. The first one works fine, but the following ones got an error at bStruct() saying "invalid redeclaration of member function bStruct::bStruct()". How did this happen, and how to fix it? Many thanks!

Comment: @goosli Please search what _re-declaration_ means, you'll find plenty of answers on SO, and if you're **really** lost, come with a new post, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector<unsigned long> Chunks(x);` the compiler will treat Chunks as a **function not a variable**.
the initialization of the struct member will not allowed in the defination of struct(class).
you can fix it using construction function:

```
struct  bStruct
{
    unsigned long   Cycles;                     
    unsigned long   Time;                                           
    std::vector<unsigned long> Chunks;
    bStruct(int x):Chunks(x) {};
};
```

Comment: Thanks!  I am very new to C++, so please bear with me. I have some more questions: 1 What does bStruct():Chunks mean or what it does? 2 Why the size of Chunks is std::vector<unsigned long>(x) instead of just x? 3 What is the usage of the curly brackets in the end? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @goosli the initialization list is more useful than assignment initialization.